# How does one set a lifecycle policy for public AWS ECR repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I have created repositories in recently announced [public AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/announcing-amazon-ecr-public-and-amazon-ecr-public-gallery/) and I'd like to [set a lifecycle policy on it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/put-lifecycle-policy.html) (in the same way as it can be done for private ECR).

Is it possible?